# How to monitor status of networkx graph creation?

Tags: python, networkx, amazon-ec2

I have a data set that is a csv/txt file representing a network.  Each line in the file contains two node name separated by a comma.  My data file contacts about 330k nodes and about 550k edges.  I am trying to create just a very rudimentary graph of this (yes, I know it will be very cluttered) using the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import numpy as np

f = open('dataFile.txt', 'rb')
G = nx.read_edgelist(f, delimiter=',', nodetype=str)
f.close()

print(nx.number_of_nodes(G))
print(nx.number_of_edges(G))

plt.figure(1)
nx.draw(G)
plt.savefig("graph.pdf")
```

I am running this on an AWS EC2 m4.4xlarge instance and it is pegging at 100% of the CPUs and only 1% of the memory.

I am skeptical by that since I thought networkx was memory intensive, not a CPU hog.  Right now, it is spinning on the nx.draw command.  Is there any way I can monitor how far into the graph generation it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Networkx is really not suited for the task. It is very slow. 
In addition, matplotlib (nx.draw) will never succeed to draw that many objects.

If you want to visualize you will need a tool to see each step of the layout where you could possibly modify what's going on.

Even though it is buggy, I would recommend [Gephi](http://gephi.org) for this. The only layout algorithm which works for large  graphs is [OpenOrd](https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/openord-layout/) (Gephi plug-ins). Don't forget not to show edges while you run the algorithm.

As a general purpose library to handle your scale of graphs I would recommend [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de). With a C++ backend and a python interface it is much faster than networkx. The drawing is also better.

Finally when you reach a million node scale, you can switch to large graph-analytics frameworks such as [Graphlab-Create](https://dato.com) or [Apache GraphX](http://spark.apache.org/graphx/).

Comment: I took your advice and went ahead to try it in GraphX.  I do not know much scala or spark (yet), but I was able to make the graph and counted the appropriate number of edges and vertices.  Definitely a learning curve, but it works!  Thank you!

Comment: There is a python API. You don't really need to use Scala. Spark is a great asset for machine learning and big data analytics. I process graph of billion of edges quite easily with it :)

Comment: Its true, but pyspark does not yet support GraphX.  Hence, scala.

Answer (score 3):

Networkx' `draw` will indeed take a long time. However, it is not the only layout / drawing function available through Networkx and your graph is not that big.

You could try [draw_graphviz](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_graphviz.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_graphviz) with something as simple as `networkx.draw_graphviz(G, 'dot')` or `networkx.draw_graphviz(G, 'neato')` (where `G` is your networkx graph).

This call will use graphviz for the node layout and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) for the actual drawing. Therefore, you better also make sure that the machine has [graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) installed (`sudo apt-get install graphviz`, `sudo pip install pygraphviz`, assuming you are running a Debian based operating system where `apt` and `pip` are available)

For an explanation of what `dot` and `neato` mean please see graphviz's website. These are two pieces of software (along with others) provided by graphviz which handle drawing of graphs (and they can be called at the command line). I have personally used them with hundreds of thousands of edges on Amazon's EC2 and while the node layout might appear to take some time, they will produce an output.

In terms of monitoring the whole process, you can issue a `top` command from a(nother) terminal and check what the process is doing but that would answer simple questions such as "Has the process stop?", "Does it keep consuming memory?" and "What percentage of the CPU time does it use right this instance?", it will not answer questions such as "What percentage of the graph has been laid out and drawn so far?". For more information about `top` please see [this link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top).

Hope this helps.

Comment: looks like draw_graphviz has been removed with the latest release (issue 2077) https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.3/release/release_2.0.html

Comment: @TytireRecubans You can always break this task down to a) Get the layout b) Draw nodes and edges. You get more control over the process in this way anyway. See [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html) for example